# Appending Data to hive Table using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to append data to already existing Table in hive.Using the Following command first i import the table from MS-SQL Server to hive.

Sqoop Command:
   `sqoop  import  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XX.XX.XX;databaseName=mydatabase"  --table    "my_table" --where "Batch_Id > 100" --username  myuser  --password mypassword --hive-import`

Now i want to append the data to same existing table in hive where "Batch_Id < 100"
I am using the following Command:

`sqoop  import  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XX.XX.XX;databaseName=mydatabase"  --table "my_table" --where "Batch_Id < 100"  --username  myuser  --password mypassword   --append  --hive-table my_table`

This command however runs successfully also updates the HDFS data, but when u connect to hive shell and query the table, the records which are appended are not visible.
Sqoop updated the Data on hdfs **"/user/hduser/my_table"** but the data on **"/user/hive/warehouse/batch_dim"** is not updated.

How can reslove this issue.

Regards,
Bhagwant Bhobe

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
sqoop  import  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XX.XX.XX;databaseName=mydatabase"  
               --table "my_table" --where "Batch_Id < 100"  
               --username  myuser  --password mypassword   
               --hive-import --hive-table my_table
```

when you are using `--hive-import` DO NOT use `--append` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The Sqoop command you're using (--import) is only for ingesting records into HDFS. You need to use the --hive-import flag to import records into Hive.

See http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive for more details and for additional import configuration options (you may want to change the document reference to your version of Sqoop, of course).